# reload, refresh, unbind, destroy, live, javascript/jquery function... how should this be done?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question title may seem confusing, let explain my situation. Any help would be much appreciated.

---

I have never done this before, hence why I can't pin point a solution in google.

I have a jquery slideshow, which I wrapped inside a function because I have some addition animation to go with it, please see below...

```
// my slider function
bikeSlider = function () {

    var slider = $('#bike-minislider').bxSlider({

        displaySlideQty: 5,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        hideControlOnEnd: true                      

    });

    $('#bike-minislider-fade').fadeIn();

};

// this runs the function
bikeSlider();
```

As you can see, immediately after the `bikeSlider` function, I run the function using... `bikeSlider();`

Now later on, I **hide some slides** within the slideshow using jquery `.hide()`.

Because my jquery slideshow function, calculates the number of visible slides within the `#bike-minislider` div, it means that the new number of visible slides causes the slideshow to not work. I guess it needs to re-calculate the new number of slides.

In a nutshell, I think this can be resolved by running the `bikeSlider();` function again.

So I tried this below, but it did not work.

```
bikeFilter = function (y) {

    $('.bike').fadeOut();
    $('.bike[data-group=' + y + ']').fadeIn();

    bikeSlider();

    return false;

}
```

As you can see I am trying to re-run the function `bikeSlider();` - but it seems to be running this over the top of the old one, so my question is, how do you remove the original slide function before running it again.

Or reloading/refreshing the original function so it re-calculate the new number slides?

Any pointers would be so helpful.

Thank You.

Comment: Did you take a look an the bxSlider Plugin? There are good Chances that there already is a function that fits your needs...

Comment: oooo - I did not see one, I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you dont need re-create slider, but you do exectly this by calling twice

```
bxSlider()
```

According doc you need reinit slider by

```
reloadShow()
//Reinitialize a slide show
```

For more info take a look here ***[bxslider](http://bxslider.com/options)*** in section **Public functions**

You need to call reloadShow() for slider-object

```
var mySlider;
$(function(){
    mySlider= $('#bike-minislider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        controls: true
    });

    mySlider.reloadShow();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this using `reloadShow(slider);` instead of `bikeSlider();` but I get **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: reloadShow** - I can't see exactly any examples of how to use a public function, can you show me please?

Comment: I did see thanks, but I'm still trying to figure it out - can't get it to it to work right.

Comment: I got a feeling if the elements are hidden using css, it may not be enough, i think the markup may need to be removed.